# how to wrap a binary operator using modern C++ instead of macros

Tags: c++

I saw a macro wrapper for binary operator on [this site](http://craftinginterpreters.com/a-virtual-machine.html) like this:

```
#define BINARY_OP(op) \                                          
  do { \                                                       
    double b = pop(); \                                        
    double a = pop(); \                                        
    push(a op b); \                                            
    } while (false)
```

and it's used like this:

```
switch(op){
  case OP_ADD:      BINARY_OP(+); break;
  case OP_SUBTRACT: BINARY_OP(-); break;
  case OP_MULTIPLY: BINARY_OP(*); break;
  case OP_DIVIDE:   BINARY_OP(/); break;
  // other ops...
}
```

but can I use a modern C++ way to implement such a wrapper instead of a macro?

Comment: I can think of several different approaches, and the best one depends on the rest of the application and how it works. You will need to figure this out by yourself, by learning more about C++ and all of its language features, such as virtual inheritance, inline functions, and templates, each one of which can be used to implement this functionality, but in different ways.

Comment: What's wrong with a function?

Comment: There is no need to use macro in this case even in non-modern C++ or even C. Just use a pointer to function and a single loop.

Comment: @JesperJuhl you mean one function for each case?

Answer (score 3):

I would do it this way:

```cpp
void BinaryOp(double (*func)(double, double))
{
    double b = pop();
    double a = pop();
    push(func(a, b));
}

// ...

case OP_ADD: BinaryOp([](double a, double b){return a + b;}) break;
```

Even if you can't use C++11 lambdas, there is no need to resort to macros. You can use the same approach if you replace lambdas with regular functions.

Comment: that seems a lot more letters to type. Is there a concise way to do it, I mean, more concise than using a macro?

Comment: @taotsi You could use an [x-macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro). But IMHO, using macros should be a last resort. In this case using one only saves you a few characters, so I'd avoid them here.

Comment: Thanks. I tried template function like `template<typename T> void BinaryOp(T func){//...}` and it works. Another question, is there any risk if I take advantage of Implicit instantiation, like `BinaryOp([](Value l, Value r){return l + r;});` instead of `BinaryOp<lambda [](double a, double b)->double>([](Value l, Value r){return l * r;});`

Comment: @taotsi The second option doesn't compile. The first one is completely fine (in fact, lambda types have no names, so even if you wanted to specify the template parameters manually, you wouldn't be able to).